# Linked Oracle and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

i have 2 server.
one using Oracle database and other using SQL Server 2008.
how i can link that server?
can anyone give me solution?

Comment: A simple google search doesn't help. ? Have a look at [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_database_link_sql_server_oracle.htm)

Comment: You'd need to install and configure [Oracle Gateway for SQL Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/gateways.112/e12069/toc.htm)

Comment: Use linked server from SQL Server, there are many many articles if you google it

Comment: i had tried using google suggest, using oracle client. but nothing happen. I will try your suggest. Thanks for comment